# Непонятные символы, закодирование блокнотом текста

Tags: php, html, кодировка, notepad++

Проблема с Notepad++, помогите если сталкивались с такой проблемой) с чем это может быть связано и как это решить?  Когда я менял кодировку своего сайта с windows-1251 на utf-8 в редакторе Notepad++, всё было нормально, но как только я запустил редактор снова, то он почему-то зашифровал весь тект написанный русскими буквами каким-то непонятным шрифтом (на скриншоте обведены красным цветом)

Как это можно решить и вернуть исходный текст?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ctrl+z же! Либо какой нибудь "online charset converter"

Comment: @rjhdby какой `ctrl+z ` если редактор закрывался?) разве онлайн конвертер справится подобной кодировкой? что-то я сомневаюсь

Comment: Попробуйте поменять еще раз кодировку на обратную. что будет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский емнип, notepad++ сохраняет историю. Хотя давно не брал его в руки конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не преобразованный файл.
Просто отобразил CP-1251 как UTF

**Шаг 1**
Меню / Кодировка / Кодировка в ANSI

Должно стать читаемым

**Шаг 2** 
Меню / Кодировка / Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM